# Issue automating Cordova application using Appium

Tags: android, cordova, appium

We have a Cordova mobile application designed for Android platform. When we use Appium Inspector to inspect element properties we do not see either resource-id or content-desc for different elements. Could anyone please help in getting locators for these elements? Or is there anything that has to be taken care during application build time for getting any identifiers?
Attaching screenshot from Appium Inspector Window and Page Source for the page for reference.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Appium Version: 1.2.3
Java Client : 2.0.0

Page Source:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ486.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue, when WebView was exposed for the application. And I could inspect element properties on different screens on the mobile application.

The developers enabled this view. If anyone else is also struggling with this issue.
Please make sure you contact your developers and ask them to enable WebView for mobile application.